# Exception thrown at 0x00D71026 in Lab13.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01AE8000**

Tags: assembly, x86, visual-studio-2019, x86-16

I have an error saying that "**Exception thrown at 0x00D71026 in Lab13.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01AE8000**" on "**mov bl,array[si]**" in right below of "**x1:**". I can build it successfully but it shows such error when I debbug it. Please help me why this makes error and how I can fix it.

Here is my code:

```
.data
array db 10h,20h,30h,40h,50h,'$'
sample db 50h
msg1 db " Element Found:$"
msg2 db " Element Not Found:$"

printmsg macro msg
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg
int 21h
int 3
endm

.code
search proc

mov ax, ds
mov ds, ax
mov al, sample
lea si, array
mov cx, 04H


x1:
mov bl,array[si]
cmp al,bl
jz x2
inc si
dec cx
jnz x1
printmsg msg2
jmp ex

x2:
printmsg msg1

     
ex:
int 3

search ENDP
END search
```

Comment: You already have the address of `array` in `si`. So you're trying to read from `[array+array]`. Change it to `mov bl,[si]`, or change `lea si, array` to `xor si,si`.

Comment: @ Michael - hi! thanks for commenting. I tried both ways but still it doesn't solve the error. 1) mov bl,[si], 16 bits register cannot be used with 32 bits address. 2)I tried also xor si,si , but same error.

Comment: Well, yeah, this is 16-bit assembly meant for DOS. You'll have to use an assembler/linker that supports such code, and run the resulting executable in something like DOSBox.

Comment: If it is for DOS, you can only have a 20-bit address, formed from a base address of the appropriate segment register shifted left 4 bits, with the address as offset.

Comment: can you show me....i don't get it..